# How to check for valid email address?

Tags: python, regex, email-validation, email-address

Is there a good way to check a form input using regex to make sure it is a proper style email address? Been searching since last night and everybody that has answered peoples questions regarding this topic also seems to have problems with it if it is a subdomained email address.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

There is no point. Even if you can verify that the email address is syntactically valid, you'll still need to check that it was not mistyped, and that it actually goes to the person you think it does. The only way to do that is to send them an email and have them click a link to verify.

Therefore, a most basic check (e.g. that they didn't accidentally entered their street address) is usually enough. Something like: it has exactly one `@` sign, and at least one `.` in the part after the `@`:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

You'd probably also want to disallow whitespace -- there are probably valid email addresses with whitespace in them, but I've never seen one, so the odds of this being a user error are on your side.

If you want the full check, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

---

Update: Here's how you could use any such regex:

```
import re

if not re.match(r"... regex here ...", email):
  # whatever
```

Python ≥3.4 has [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) which is preferable to `re.match`.

Note the `r` in front of the string; this way, you won't need to escape things twice.

If you have a large number of regexes to check, it might be faster to compile the regex first:

```
import re

EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r"... regex here ...")

if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(email):
  # whatever
```

---

Another option is to use the [`validate_email`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address/28982264#28982264) package, which actually contacts the SMTP server to verify that the address exists. This still doesn't guarantee that it belongs to the right person, though.

Comment: So than basically my best bet would be `if not re.match("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email):` ?

Comment: I ended up doing `if not re.match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*$", email):` as this seem the most plausible scenario followed by sending an verification email to the given address.

Comment: +1 for the quickie re.match(r"xx") tutorial. Inlining what is necessary is the mark of a good answer.

Comment: @Bobby: *please* loosen that up a lot. I've had to deal with email addresses that that would filter out (e.g. with `/`, seen in a University's addresses). Another whole class that you're entirely blocking are internationalised domain names. Really, there's no good reason to block valid email addresses. I'll begrudgingly forgive people that don't allow email addresses like `100%." foo b@r"(this is a cool email address!)@(just a tld)com(ok)`, but I think the check for an `@` symbol is really all you should have (a top level domain is valid as the domain part, but it's improbable).

Comment: I wanted something a little tighter than this answer.  In particular, no whitespace, can't end with a period, and matches through the end of the string.  This should catch 99% of typos. Here it is: `EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r"[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s.]+$")`

Comment: Making it even a little tighter.  Seems safe to limit TLD to alphanumeric right now (still haven't seen a TLD that has non-ASCII chars).  Using this now: `re.compile(r"[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")`

Comment: Except that `"@"@localhost` and `\@@localhost` are valid.

Comment: I like this answer the most however if you do want to add some more robustness to the local part of the email (before the @) while still keeping the general "there is no point attitude" you can do something like:

    ``r'[\w!#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.]+@[\w\.-]+'``

Comment: *hijacking the accepted answer*: take a look at this non-regex answer with python libs, including checking if the domain has an smtp server and even polling the smtp server to see if the email exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982264/2327328

Comment: if anyone is unsure, the [^@] means match anything except @. I was unsure myself and found the answer @w3schools don't laugh !

Comment: [^<\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[a-zA-Z]+ using the answer and comments came up with this. If using SMTP stuff you might have brackets around your address and your address might be preceded by a person's name. This should extract the address only, no brackets.

Comment: One note for `fullmatch`, in my case for emails like "to1@domain.com" it does match, but doesn't fullmatch. Match is actually `to1@domain.c`, so `om` is omitted.

Comment: Sorry but "it has exactly one sign @" is a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Snowirbis I don't know about the RFC, but I have never seen a _practical_ example of an email address with more than one `@`. If this does occur, it's more likely to be user error (for example, the user hit Ctrl+V twice by accident) than someone's actual email address.

Comment: note that the above regexp is vulnerable to ReDOS attack
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-redos-attack/

Comment: @Moussawi7 That's interesting. Can you elaborate? What kind of inputs would result in exponential-time behaviour?

Comment: @Thomas sorry I deleted my comments, like you mentioned wrong thread

Answer (score 178):

The Python standard library comes with an e-mail parsing function: [`email.utils.parseaddr()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr).

It returns a two-tuple containing the real name and the actual address parts of the e-mail:

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> parseaddr('foo@example.com')
('', 'foo@example.com')

>>> parseaddr('Full Name <full@example.com>')
('Full Name', 'full@example.com')

>>> parseaddr('"Full Name with quotes and <weird@chars.com>" <weird@example.com>')
('Full Name with quotes and <weird@chars.com>', 'weird@example.com')
```

And if the parsing is unsuccessful, it returns a two-tuple of empty strings:

```
>>> parseaddr('[invalid!email]')
('', '')
```

An issue with this parser is that it's accepting of anything that is considered as a valid e-mail address for RFC-822 and friends, including many things that are clearly not addressable on the wide Internet:

```
>>> parseaddr('invalid@example,com') # notice the comma
('', 'invalid@example')

>>> parseaddr('invalid-email')
('', 'invalid-email')
```

So, as @TokenMacGuy put it, the only definitive way of checking an e-mail address is to send an e-mail to the expected address and wait for the user to act on the information inside the message.

However, you might want to check for, at least, the presence of an @-sign on the second tuple element, as @bvukelic suggests:

```
>>> '@' in parseaddr("invalid-email")[1]
False
```

If you want to go a step further, you can install the [dnspython](https://pypi.org/project/dnspython/) project and resolve the mail servers for the e-mail domain (the part after the '@'), only trying to send an e-mail if there are actual `MX` servers:

```
>>> from dns.resolver import query
>>> domain = 'foo@bar@google.com'.rsplit('@', 1)[-1]
>>> bool(query(domain, 'MX'))
True
>>> query('example.com', 'MX')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  [...]
dns.resolver.NoAnswer
>>> query('not-a-domain', 'MX')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  [...]
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN
```

You can catch both `NoAnswer` and `NXDOMAIN` by catching `dns.exception.DNSException`.

And Yes, `foo@bar@google.com` is a syntactically valid address. Only the last `@` should be considered for detecting where the domain part starts.

Comment: @PeterLada: You could just check if there's a `@` in the address after using this func, though.

Comment: @PeterLada, Thanks for the input. Fixed the module name.

Comment: `parseaddr(u"evil@addr")` will break this.

Comment: @Yajo, "break this" how?`evil@addr` is just as valid an e-mail address as `nonexistinglogin@valid-domain.com` and is treated as such by `parseaddr()`. In the end, you'll always need to try sending an e-mail to the provided address for validation.

Comment: email.utils.parseaddr parses email address but does not validate it
`email.utils.parseaddr('user@@host')`
yields `('', 'user@')`

Comment: @skoval00, that looks like a bug in parseaddr... it should have been parsed as `('', 'user@@host')` instead I think.

Comment: @skoval00, exactly, I tried this one: In [8]: parseaddr('VIRUS <virus!@variable.:p>')
Out[8]: ('VIRUS', 'virus!@variable.')

Comment: if I pass in an invalid address: 'doijf oijoij yoyoyo@yoyo.com' it returns a valid tuple of ('', 'doijf oijoij yoyoyo@yoyo.com'). How does a space get through the validation....?

Comment: According to this function "124514123124512" is also a valid email ?

Comment: I'm not sure why so many upvotes. This is useless since it does pretty much no validations whatsoever, which was the original question.

Answer (score 94):

I haven't seen the answer already here among the mess of custom Regex answers, but...

There exists a python library called **[py3-validate-email](https://github.com/karolyi/py3-validate-email)** <s>[validate_email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email)</s> which has 3 levels of email validation, including asking a valid SMTP server if the email address is valid (without sending an email).

To install

```
python -m pip install py3-validate-email
```

Basic usage:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email(email_address='example@example.com', \
    check_regex=True, check_mx=True, \
    from_address='my@from.addr.ess', helo_host='my.host.name', \ 
    smtp_timeout=10, dns_timeout=10, use_blacklist=True)
```

---

For those interested in the dirty details, validate_email.py ([source](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/blob/master/validate_email.py)) aims to be faithful to [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

> All we are really doing is comparing the input string to one
> gigantic regular expression.  But building that regexp, and
> ensuring its correctness, is made much easier by assembling it
> from the "tokens" defined by the RFC.  Each of these tokens is
> tested in the accompanying unit test file.

---

<s>you *may* need the pyDNS module for checking SMTP servers</s>

```
pip install pyDNS
```

or from Ubuntu

```
apt-get install python3-dns
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get python3-dns` seems to work on Ubuntu in place of `sudo -H pip3 install pyDNS`, just for the record.

Comment: This thing returns "True" for just about anything I throw at it.

Comment: @Prof.Falken which of the 3 tests are you referring to (valid syntax, valid smtp, valid mailbox)?

Comment: @philshem, well, the two deeper tests supposed to go out to the mail servers, both return "None" all the time.  Don't know why, I will try to rule out that I have some kind of limitation on the network I am on. The simple test, valid syntax, I can throw just about anything to and it will say it's good syntax. I used the pip module in Python 2.

Comment: Same result as @Prof.Falken

Comment: This is a pretty bad validator. It fails for `email@examplecom`. See the big list of known [issues](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues).

Comment: There seems to be a newer version for validate_email : https://pypi.org/project/py3-validate-email/.

Comment: It does not work well.
https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues/93
https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues/109

Comment: @Vladimir I've updated the answer to include the new package which seems to be more supported https://pypi.org/project/py3-validate-email/
(thanks @krishnaa)

Comment: having trouble with pyDNS please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342551/error-installing-pydns/62371748#62371748

Comment: Before discarding the "email_validator" package ( https://pypi.org/project/email-validator/ ) I think it's prudent to have a look here ( https://stackabuse.com/validate-email-addresses-in-python-with-email-validator/ ) and here ( https://pythonhosted.org/TurboMail/chapters/detailed.html ). There is another Python package (built-in "email") that can also solve the problem ( https://kalunite.net/parsing-email-addresses-in-python.html ). But if you really want to use Regex, this is the way ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/74925719/3223785 ).

Comment: I opted for "email_validator" because it has a more sophisticated and realistic implementation and provides facilities such as out-of-the-box domain validation.

Comment: Another cool reference ( https://morioh.com/p/c72092113c59 ) about "email_validator" package.

Answer (score 24):

Email addresses are not as simple as they seem!  For example, Bob_O'Reilly+tag@example.com, is a valid email address.

I've had some luck with the lepl package (http://www.acooke.org/lepl/).  It can validate email addresses as indicated in RFC 3696: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3696.html

Found some old code:

```
import lepl.apps.rfc3696
email_validator = lepl.apps.rfc3696.Email()
if not email_validator("email@example.com"):
    print "Invalid email"
```

Comment: `lepl` has now been discontinued.

Comment: For a simple use case like this, if the current version works the fact it's discontinued is not very relevant.

Comment: this method doesn't work when u put email
email''sfsf@sadasdas.adsdsa.com.com'
It return true for this username too

Comment: It seems to return False for everything I tried it with, valid or not.

Answer (score 16):

I found an excellent (and tested) way to check for valid email address. I paste my code here:

```
# here i import the module that implements regular expressions
import re

# here is my function to check for valid email address
def test_email(your_pattern):
  pattern = re.compile(your_pattern)
  # here is an example list of email to check it at the end
  emails = ["john@example.com", "python-list@python.org", "wha.t.`1an?ug{}ly@email.com"]
  for email in emails:
    if not re.match(pattern, email):
        print "You failed to match %s" % (email)
    elif not your_pattern:
        print "Forgot to enter a pattern!"
    else:
        print "Pass"

# my pattern that is passed as argument in my function is here!
pattern = r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+\.\w+)\"?"   

# here i test my function passing my pattern
test_email(pattern)
```

Comment: The only answer here I see here. 
That checks for characters allowed in [RFC 6531](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6531) email standards.

Comment: also the plus sign is allowed in the username part of email

Comment: Copy web https://www.learnpython.org/en/Regular_Expressions .. only a problem 3rd email is wrong, its invalid cannot special character.

Comment: This pattern does not allow the underscore character in email addresses.

Answer (score 7):

I see a lot of complicated answers here.  Some of them, fail to knowledge simple, true email address, or have false positives.  Below, is the simplest way of testing that the string would be a valid email.  It tests against 2 and 3 letter TLD's.  Now that you technically can have larger ones, you may wish to increase the 3 to 4, 5 or even 10.

```
import re
def valid_email(email):
  return bool(re.search(r"^[\w\.\+\-]+\@[\w]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$", email))
```

Comment: however `re.match` is better than `bool(re.search)`

Comment: That won't work for UK emails for the record, they end with `.co.uk`.

Comment: This won't work for any TLDs that are more than 3 characters

Comment: will this validate emails such as `user@department.company.com` (because it has 2 dots in the domain name part) ?

Comment: @Peter  Now it can handle your use case.

Comment: @kbuilds "won't work for any TLDs that are more than 3 characters" 
This is why I specifically address this and say it will work for any 2 or 3 letter TLDs but you may wish to increase it by editing.... you need to read my text, not just copy the code dude.  I covered this, and explained how to make it work for those.

Comment: @PyTis It's encouraging to see that you came back after over 5 years to leave me this comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is typically solved using regex. There are many variations of solutions however. Depending on how strict you need to be, and if you have custom requirements for validation, or will accept any valid email address.

See this page for reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 5):

Email addresses are incredibly complicated. Here's a sample regex that will match every RFC822-valid address:
http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

You'll notice that it's probably longer than the rest of your program. There are even whole modules for Perl with the purpose of validating email addresses. So you probably won't get anything that's 100% perfect as a regex while also being readable. Here's a sample recursive descent parser:
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ABIGAIL/RFC-RFC822-Address-2009110702/lib/RFC/RFC822/Address.pm

but you'll need to decide whether you need perfect parsing or simple code.

Comment: According to this documentation ( https://pythonhosted.org/TurboMail/chapters/detailed.html ) "the original format for email messages was defined in RFC 822 which was superseded by RFC 2822. The newest standard document about the format is currently RFC 5322.". So, using something based on RFC 822 valid? 

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
def email():
    email = raw_input("enter the mail address::")
     match = re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+.\w+', email)

    if match:
        print "valid email :::", match.group()
    else:
        print "not valid:::"

email()
```

Comment: Nice one - I think, though, the "." before the TLD needs to be escaped as "\."

Answer (score 5):

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
print(bool(is_valid))
```

See [validate_email docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email).

Comment: This library is buggy and has been giving a lot of false negatives, causing headache.

Comment: this library thinks "example@so" is good email

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take out the mail from a long string or file Then try this.

```
([^@|\s]+@[^@]+\.[^@|\s]+)
```

Note, this will work when you have a space before and after your email-address. if you don't have space or have some special chars then you may try modifying it.

Working example:

```
string="Hello ABCD, here is my mail id example@me.com "
res = re.search("([^@|\s]+@[^@]+\.[^@|\s]+)",string,re.I)
res.group(1)
```

This will take out `example@me.com` from this string.

Also, note this may not be the right answer... But I have posted it here to help someone who has specific requirement like me

Comment: ´re.match("([^@|\s]+@[^@]+\.[^@|\s]+)",email)´ works great

Answer (score 1):

For check of email use [email_validator](https://pypi.org/project/email_validator/)

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError

def check_email(email):
    try:
        v = validate_email(email)  # validate and get info
        email = v["email"]  # replace with normalized form
        print("True")
    except EmailNotValidError as e:
        # email is not valid, exception message is human-readable
        print(str(e))

check_email("test@gmailcom")
```

Comment: It may be helpful to understand the "practical" intent of this package: "This library validates that a string is of the form name@example.com. This is the sort of validation you would want for an email-based login form on a website."

Answer (score 0):

```
"^[\w\.\+\-]+\@[\w]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
```

Comment: Generally, answers, *especially* to regex-related questions, are much more helpful if they include a fairly detailed explanation of what the code or regex is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is still more important with something that is as frankly error-prone and fiddly as email address validation; I've seen at least one regex that was **a full page long** for the purpose, and that was *without* insignificant whitespace.

Comment: This appears to be helpful:

`return re.search("^[\w\.\+\-]+\@[\w]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$", email) != None`

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be a practical implementation:

```
^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+$
```

Comment: `[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+` This is wrong because this will allow spaces in the extension part `.c om` and spaces are not allowed in emails.

Comment: no it won't allow those spaces, that's why it the last part has the \s. example: re.findall(r'[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+', 'john@smith.this has spaces') = ['john@smith.this']

Comment: EDIT: I was using `r.match` and `re.compile` to test, not `re.findall` so perhaps, we are both correct if used as intended. Unfortunately, you did not provide any details in your answer, and therefore, it was open to misunderstanding. If you edit your answer, I will be able to remove the downvote. Unfortunately, without your answer edit, the system will not let me to change my vote.

Answer (score -1):

Finding Email-id:
[image: finding IP screenshot]

```
import re 
a=open("aa.txt","r")
#c=a.readlines() 
b=a.read()
c=b.split("\n")
print(c)
  for d in c: 
    obj=re.search(r'[\w.]+\@[\w.]+',d)
    if obj:
      print(obj.group())  
#for more calcification click on image above..
```

Comment: Please edit the code so the indentation is correct, remove the line numbers and press ctrl + K with the code selected to format it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this filter mask on email input:
emailMask:  `/[\w.\-@'"!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]/i`

Answer (score -3):

email validation

```
import re
def validate(email): 
    match=re.search(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]*\.*[com|org|edu]{3}$)",email)
    if match:
        return 'Valid email.'
    else:
        return 'Invalid email.'
```

Answer (score -4):

The only really accurate way of distinguishing real, valid email addresses from invalid ones is to *send mail to it*.  What counts as an email is surprisingly convoluted (`"John Doe" <john.doe@example.com>"` actually is a valid email address), and you most likely want the email address to actually send mail to it later.  After it passes some basic sanity checks (such as in Thomas's answer, has an `@` and at least one `.` after the `@`), you should probably just send an email verification letter to the address, and wait for the user to follow a link embedded in the message to confirm that the email was valid.