# Regular Expression for Email address

Tags: python

Here is a weird regular expression for emails .

We can have various kind of email addresses

string1@somemail.com

string1@somemail.co.in

string1.string2@somemail.com

string1.string2@somemail.co.in

The following regular expression can find any of the mails above

```
email2="santa.banta@gmail.co.in"
email1="arindam31@yahoo.co.in'"
email="bogusemail123@sillymail.com"
email3="santa.banta.manta@gmail.co.in"
email4="santa.banta.manta@gmail.co.in.xv.fg.gh"
email5="abc.dcf@ghj.org"
email6="santa.banta.manta@gmail.co.in.org"





re.search('\w+[.|\w]\w+@\w+[.]\w+[.|\w+]\w+',email)

x=re.search('\w+[.|\w]\w+@\w+[.]\w+[.|\w+]\w+',email2)
x.group()
santa.banta@gmail.co.in'
x=re.search('\w+[.|\w]\w+@\w+[.]\w+[.|\w+]\w+',email1)
x.group()
arindam31@yahoo.co.in'
x=re.search('\w+[.|\w]\w+@\w+[.]\w+[.|\w+]\w+',email)
x.group()
'bogusemail123@sillymail.com'
```

This seems too complicated right...

I generalized it a bit....

```
x=re.search('(\w+[.|\w])*@(\w+[.])*\w+',email4)
x.group()
'santa.banta.manta@gmail.co.in.xv.fg.gh'
```

The above regular expression now can detect any type of combination...

Now if you want only email address ending with '.in' or '.com' 
then you can add a variation...

```
x=re.search('(\w+[.|\w])*@(\w+[.])*(com$|in$)',email)
```

You can try out this on various combinations....
If the expression does not fit anywhere , do tell me .

Some assumptions I have used : email address(username) wont contain special characters , only words or numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python check for valid email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address)

Comment: @phihag I do not think it is a dupe, I think it's not even a question, actually.

Comment: 1: What's the question? 2: Using regular expressions to validate email addresses is a very very deep rabbit hole, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Comment: Sorry for the above post...I meant to share what I did...Its not a question...Its just info sharing...

Answer (score 3):

As [answered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses), the [correct regexp for emails](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is way more complicated than that.

Comment: I do not know if this is a duplicate........i worked on it .....thought it was worth sharing........Its not a question ......Just something i thought worth sharing.......

Comment: regardless of what the folks @ stack overflow care to disregard as tripe, Arindam's post was EXTREEEEEEMELY MF helpful to me, personally. Plus it helps their SEO. Just sayin...