# Filtering string in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, invalid-characters

I am making algorithm for checking the string (e-mail) - like "E-mail addres is valid"  but their are rules. First part of e-mail has to be string that has 1-8 characters (can contain  alphabet, numbers, underscore [ _ ]...all the parts that e-mail contains) and after @ the second part of e-mail has to have string that has 1-12 characters (also containing all legal expressions) and it has to end with top level domain .com

```
email = raw_input ("Enter the e-mail address:")
length = len (email)
if length > 20 
    print "Address is too long"
elif lenght < 7:
    print "Address is too short"  
if not email.endswith (".com"):   
    print "Address doesn't contain correct domain ending"   
try:
    first_part = len (splitting[0])
    second_part = len(splitting[1])  

    account = splitting[0]
    domain = splitting[1] 

    list = "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_."

    for c in account: 
        if c not in list:
            print "Invalid char", "->", c,"<-", "in account name of e-mail"

    for c in domain:
        if c not in list:
            print "Invalid char", "->", c,"<-", "in domain name of  e-mail"

    if first_part == 0:
        print "You need at least 1 character before the @"
    elif first_part> 8:
        print "The first part is too long"
    if second_part == 4:
        print "You need at least 1 character after the @"
    elif second_part> 16:
        print "The second part is too long"
except IndexError:
        print ""The address must consist of 2 parts connected with symbol @,\
 and ending must be .com"

    if first_part > 0 and first_part < 8 and second_part >4 and second_part < 16:
       print "Valid e-mail address"
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? post what you've tried rather than just a specification.

Comment: Have you Googled, "Email address validation" or "Email regex" or "How can I verify if an email address is real"?  What have you tried? See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask.  Just for the record, if you show what you've done so far you will most likely earn back your -1's

Comment: I'm a first year student at information science and we are just starting with python...this is our first weekend assignment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=E-Mail+address+validation+[python]

Comment: This is not really a Python related question, as it applies to almost every programming language. Take a look at this http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: email = raw_input ("Enter the e-mail address:")
length = len (email)
if length in range (5, 12):
     print "length is good"
elif length <5:
     print "Address is too short!"
elif length> 12:
     print "Address is too long"                                              -------------------------------------------------------------------- this is the best i can do with my knowledge....and we cant use regular expressions, we are going to learn them later...

Comment: @user1459182 edit your question to improve it, don't post code in comments

Comment: Do you know about `for` loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address

Comment: @JoshMein Not a dupe. He is explicitly disallowed from using regex.

Comment: Also, look up python's `split` function and consider how you could use that on the entered email address. (Hint: it's useful at least twice)

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl I found the duplicate before he made his most recent edit, and I did not notice the most recent stipulations when I posted it. Still I am pretty sure even without regex there are other possible dups for this question. It has been asked countless times on SO.

Comment: split method uses spaces as separators                                so I can split the adres after and before the @ but still how to compare all legal expressions in these 2 parts  of email...email.split("@")

Comment: Write out how you would do this on paper. `take first part of string and make sure it has a certain amount of characters`...`make sure the last four characters are .com` and then go through each part and solve it.

Comment: Yes he's asking a homework question and yes he's new to the site and went about asking the wrong way but I was under the impression homework questions are allowed on SO. There's nothing wrong with this question now that he's added the code he has so far. I don't think we should give him a working solution, obviously, but I do think it should be re-opened.

Comment: Starting to get grasp on this problem, but I still need help...as you can see I'm still new to Python and this site, so apologies for inconvenience..

Comment: Have you tried playing around in a python interpreter? Give IDLE a shot and have a good read of http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: OMG...so much...basically you can do anything with that...

Comment: Instead of 20 edits (which also caused it to become Community Wiki meaning no points are now awarded) you could wait until you have finished and do one edit..

Comment: I am not here for points, I am here for learning Python and trying to get right answer...and if possible to help someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you got everything working, except the part of finding invalid chars. Is that true?

Do you know the `for` loop? It may be helpful to you. Just get the parts of the e-mail:

```
account = splitting[0]
domain = splitting[1]
```

Then, iterate over each part. It will yield a character each time. If this char is not in the set of allowed ones, you print a message:

```
for c in account:
    if c not in "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_.":
        print "Invalid char", c, "in e-mail"

for c in domain:
    if c not in "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_.":
        print "Invalid char", c, "in e-mail"
```

This is not a very elegant solution (one could use [`string.ascii_letters`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters)`+`[`string.digits`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.digits)`+"._"` instead of `"abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_."`, for example, or [list comprehesions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)), but I bet it is sufficiently understandable for a new user.

Comment: True, invalid chars was the main problem                                   We can agree this is not a very elegant solution, but it will sure do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

[Regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) FTW!

```
import re

address = 'test@gmail.com'
if re.match(r'^[a-z0-9_]{1,8}@[a-z0-9_]{1,8}\.com$', address, re.IGNORECASE):
  print 'valid'
else:
  print 'invalid'
```

A shorter regular expression (as the comments note) would be `r'^\w{1,8}@\w{1,8}\.com$'`

I don't know if that's what your teacher is aiming for, but regex are always good to know :)

Comment: Fixed some subtle bugs. You had `\\.` instead of `\.` (the first matches a literal `\ ` followed by any character, the second matches a literal `.`, which is what you intended.) I also cleaned up your character classes - using `\d` instead of `0-9`, and `a-zA-Z` instead of the ignore-case flag, which may not work like you expect for international users.

Comment: I really resent this edit of yours. (1) You changed my wording and removed FTW (2) you added the escaping bug when you added the `r''` prefix (3) you introduced a bug into the code where the total length of what comes after `@` can be 16 and not 12 (4) you changed my coding style and made the code less verbose with the removal of `re.I`.

If you have issues with my answer, leave a comment. Don't go around messing with other people's wording and code.

Comment: `\w` could be used instead of `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

Comment: You're right. I was going for verbosity, but it's definitely worth mentioning the shorter syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a validate email method, with two parameters the email address to validate and a list of valid domains.

```
def validEmail(email, domains):

    length = len(email)

    index = email.find('@')

    if len(email[0:index]) <= 8 and len(email[0:index]) > 0:
        dot = email.find('.')
        if (len(email[index + 1:]) - dot) <= 12:
            if index+1==dot:
                return False
            else:
                for i in domains:
                    if email[dot + 1:] == i:
                        return True
    return False

domains = ['com', 'org', 'co.uk']

email = raw_input ("Enter the e-mail address:")
print validEmail(email, domains)
```

Comment: You've just invalidated your code by undoing my edit. I can't roll-back your edit and don't want to get into an edit war with anyone. However, if could please re-instate the spaces you've just removed I'd be grateful.