# finding email address in a web page using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, search, html

I'm a beginner-level student of Python. Here is the code I have to find instances of email addresses from a web page.

```
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://website/category")
    reg_ex = re.compile(r'[-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+)(\.[-a-z0-9]+)+', re.IGNORECASE
    m = reg_ex.search_all(page)
    m.group()
```

When I ran it, the Python module said that there is an invalid syntax and it is on the line:

```
    m = reg_ex.search_all(page)
```

Would anyone tell me why it is invalid?

Answer (score 6):

Consider an alternative:

```
## Suppose we have a text with many email addresses
str = 'purple alice@google.com, blah monkey bob@abc.com blah dishwasher'

## Here re.findall() returns a list of all the found email strings
emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', str) 
    ## ['alice@google.com', 'bob@abc.com']    
for email in emails:
    # do something with each found email string
    print email
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Comment: This might be the solution the OP is looking for, but it does not answer his question...

Comment: So if the OP asks a question where he is trying to get a certain output and asks why his code doesn't work, I am only supposed to tell him why his code doesn't work and not give him a better solution?

Comment: No, do both. Explain why his didn't work then provide a solution and explain why it does work.

Comment: It was explained 4 times why his doesn't work, so I didn't want to be redundant.

Comment: this regex can also match invalid email like name@example without ltd extention.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have closing `)` at this line:

```
reg_ex = re.compile(r'[a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+)(\.[-a-z0-9]+)+', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Plus, your regex is not valid, try this instead:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
```

FYI, validating email using regex is not that trivial, see these threads:

- [Python check for valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address)
- [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Your suggested regex makes no sense in this use case. The OP wants to find an email address in a bunch of text, so the anchors are wrong here.

Comment: @stema ok, it was just an example, but correct, no need to put boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Besides, `reg_ex` has no `search_all` method. And you should pass in `page.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `.search_all` method with the **re** module

maybe theone you are looking for is `.findall`

you can try

```
re.findall(r"(\w(?:[-.+]?\w+)+\@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[-+]?\w+)*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})", text)
```

i assume `text` is the text to search, in your case should be `text = page.read()`

or you need to compile the regex:

```
r = re.compile(r"(\w(?:[-.+]?\w+)+\@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-+]?\w+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,})", re.I)
results = r.findall(text)
```

Note:
`.findall` returns a list of matches

if you need to iterate to get a match object, you can use `.finditer`

(from the example before)

```
r = re.compile(r"(\w(?:[-.+]?\w+)+\@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-+]?\w+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,})", re.I)
for email_match in r.finditer(text):
    email_addr = email_match.group() #or anything you need for a matched object
```

Now the problem is what Regex you have to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `r'[-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+)(\.[-a-z0-9]+)+'` to `r'[aA-zZ0-9._]+@([aA-zZ0-9]+)(\.[aA-zZ0-9]+)+'`. The `-` character before **a-z** is the cause