# Email validation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I am doing email validation in Rails with:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
```

Also, I do HTML5 validation in the frontend but email addresses like

```
..abc@gmail.com
.abc@gmail.com
```

still are valid. What am I missing?

Comment: Those are valid emails

Comment: @FrederickCheung: apparently, they aren't: http://isemail.info/..abc%40gmail.com

Comment: @SergioTulentsev cool didn't know about that site. I can receive email sent to such an address, so some implementations would appear to ignore that restriction.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: checked with gmail, doesn't work. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I tested with gmail too - can hardly complain when non spec behaviour is inconsistent though.

Comment: In most cases it's better to let some invalid addresses through than to block valid ones. Point being, don't make it overly strict unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxX81WmXjPg

Answer (score 268, accepted):

I use the constant built into URI in the standard ruby library

```
validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
```

warning - this considers `a@b` to be a valid email address

Comment: Attention! I tried this using a wrong email  `!('fakeemail@gmailcom' =~ URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP).nil?` it should returns false but it returns true which is not correct

Comment: `fakeemail@gmailcom` is a valid email, check here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: This method does not check domain

Comment: If there is a period, but nothing after it, the regex will return nil.  If there is something after the period or no period, it will pass.

"This requirement is a willful violation of RFC 5322, which defines a syntax for e-mail addresses that is simultaneously too strict (before the "@" character), too vague (after the "@" character), and too lax (allowing comments, whitespace characters, and quoted strings in manners unfamiliar to most users) to be of practical use here."

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address

Comment: @medBouzid because fakeemail@gmailcom is in valid email format. I would check the domain next.

Comment: Amazing! I just checked and this is the regex under the hood of `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`:
```/\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\z/``` .  Love this solution

Comment: For noobs : email.match(URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP).present? will work if looking for non active record solution

Comment: not sure if its only me, but using the above solution i still get email staring with `.` as valid.

Comment: Validations like this will also need an error message, [here is an example](https://gist.github.com/frankolson/96fdd5706b779d52d7fbbdc201f1cc8f) with a custom message. Also here is a link to the URI source documentation: [Ruby Standard Library: URI::MailTo](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/URI/MailTo)

Comment: Attention! It returns true for `abc...xyz@gmail.com` email id.

Comment: Keep in mind that client-side email validation happens "for free" if you use the email input type. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

Comment: @cdmo - you can't count on that if exposing your API to other clients though.

Answer (score 34):

If you use the Devise gem already in your app, it might be opportune to use

```ruby
email =~ Devise.email_regexp
```

...which also means different places of the app use the same validation.

If you want to add it as an attribute validator to your ActiveRecord model:

```ruby
validates :email, format: { with: Devise.email_regexp }
```

Comment: The Device regex is quite simple: /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
The following email addresses are not detected as invalid: info@example,com, info@example, info,foo@example.com

Comment: I use validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[^@,\s]+@[^@,\s]+\.[^@,\s]+\z/ in my model now. The Regex is the one from Devise, but modified to deny the examples above.

Comment: Yes this looks cool to me.
`validates :email, format: { with: Devise.email_regexp, message: "invalid email" }`

Comment: This will not check if the email is valid, it will just check if your string contains `@` char and there is no whitespace.
`# Email regex used to validate email formats. It asserts that there are no
  # @ symbols or whitespaces in either the localpart or the domain, and that
  # there is a single @ symbol separating the localpart and the domain.
  mattr_accessor :email_regexp
  @@email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/`

Comment: if you're using devise already, your user model should already be doing this

Comment: @AHK AFAIK, it's really hard to "properly" validate email addresses with a Regexp. So usually people either just do a light sanity check like Devise, or use a service and actually send an email to check, depending on requirements. See also this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxX81WmXjPg

Answer (score 31):

#### Update: I just found the [valid_email2](https://github.com/lisinge/valid_email2) gem which looks pretty great.

Don't use a regular expression for email address validation. It's a trap. There are way more valid email address formats than you'll think of. However! The `mail` gem (it's required by ActionMailer, so you have it) will parse email addresses — with a proper parser — for you:

```
require 'mail'
a = Mail::Address.new('foo@example.com')
```

This will throw a `Mail::Field::ParseError` if it's a non-compliant email address. (We're not getting into things like doing an MX address lookup or anything.)

If you want the good ol' Rails validator experience, you can make `app/models/concerns/email_validatable.rb`:

```
require 'mail'

module EmailValidatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      begin
        a = Mail::Address.new(value)
      rescue Mail::Field::ParseError
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then in your model, you can:

```
include EmailValidatable
validates :email, email: true
```

As Iwo Dziechciarow's comment below mentions, this passes anything that's a valid "To:" address through. So something like `Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>` is valid. This might be a problem for you, it might not; it really *is* a valid address, after all.

If you do want just the address portion of it:

```
a = Mail::Address.new('Foo Bar <foobar@example.com>')
a.address
=> "foobar@example.com"
```

As Björn Weinbrenne notes below, there are way more valid [RFC2822 addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4) than you may expect (I'm quite sure all of the addresses listed there are compliant, and may receive mail depending system configurations) — this is why I don't recommend trying a regex, but using a compliant parser.

If you really care whether you can send email to an address then **your best bet — by far — is to actually send a message with a verification link.**

Comment: interesting approach - though this will also accept values like `'Mikel Lindsaar (My email address) <mikel@test.lindsaar.net>'` with the display_name and comments - which probably isn't what you always want, but you can probably get the parsed address alone (`a.address`) and overwrite the attribute with that value

Comment: It doesn't detect the following as invalid: info@example,com, info@example, info,foo@example.com

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are all RFC2822-compliant addresses. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: I'm unable to get any errors using `Mail::Address.new('fake')`. Don't tell me the email address `fake` is RFC compliant.

Comment: I think it is, it would be to the user 'fake' on the local system. You probably want to make sure `domain` is something you like reasonably well.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the new rails way to do email validation:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
```

Refer to the [Rails validations doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates).

Comment: Always is good idea to scroll to bottom. Only one point against is it accepts `foo,bar@hooli.com`. Not a problem for my situation.

Answer (score 9):

@Nate Thank you so much for putting this answer together.  I did not realize email validation had so many nuances until I looked at your code snippet.

I noticed that the current mail gem: mail-2.6.5 doesn't throw an error for an email of "abc".  Examples:

```
>> a = Mail::Address.new('abc')
=> #<Mail::Address:70343701196060 Address: |abc| >
>> a.address # this is weird
=> "abc"
>> a = Mail::Address.new('"Jon Doe" <jon@doe.com>')
=> #<Mail::Address:70343691638900 Address: |Jon Doe <jon@doe.com>| >
>> a.address
=> "jon@doe.com"
>> a.display_name
=> "Jon Doe"
>> Mail::Address.new('"Jon Doe <jon')
Mail::Field::ParseError: Mail::AddressList can not parse |"Jon Doe <jon|
Reason was: Only able to parse up to "Jon Doe <jon
  from (irb):3:in `new'
  from (irb):3
>>
```

It does throw `Mail::Field::ParseError` errors for `"Jon Doe <jon` which is great.  I believe will check for the simple "abc pattern" also.

In `app/models/concerns/pretty_email_validatable.rb`:

```
require 'mail'

module PrettyEmailValidatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class PrettyEmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      begin
        a = Mail::Address.new(value)
      rescue Mail::Field::ParseError
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
      end

      # regexp from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html
      value = a.address
      unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

and then in your model, you can:

```
include PrettyEmailValidatable
validates :pretty_email, email: true
```

So I use the above for "pretty email" validation and the https://github.com/balexand/email_validator for standard email validation.

Comment: `Mail::Address.new('abc')` is for mail to the local network. Check the [valid_email2](https://github.com/lisinge/valid_email2) gem. Really, send a test email.

Answer (score 8):

If anybody else is very TDD focused: I wanted something that I could write tests against and improve upon later if needed, without tying the tests to another model.

Building off of [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12779/nate) and [tongueroo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361692/tongueroo)'s code (Thanks [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12779/nate) and [tongueroo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361692/tongueroo)!), this was done in `Rails 5`, `Ruby 2.4.1`. Here's what I threw into `app/validators/email_validator.rb`:

```rb
require 'mail'

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def add_error(record, attribute)
    record.errors.add(attribute, (options[:message] || "is not a valid email address"))
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    begin
      a = Mail::Address.new(value)
    rescue Mail::Field::ParseError
      add_error(record, attribute)
    end

    # regexp from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html
    value = a.address unless a.nil?
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      add_error(record, attribute)
    end
  end
end
```

And this is by no means comprehensive, but here's what I threw into `spec/validators/email_validator_spec.rb`:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe EmailValidator do
  subject do
    Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations
      attr_accessor :email
      validates :email, email: true
    end.new
  end

  context 'when the email address is valid' do
    let(:email) { Faker::Internet.email }

    it 'allows the input' do
      subject.email = email
      expect(subject).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context 'when the email address is invalid' do
    let(:invalid_message) { 'is not a valid email address' }

    it 'invalidates the input' do
      subject.email = 'not_valid@'
      expect(subject).not_to be_valid
    end

    it 'alerts the consumer' do
      subject.email = 'notvalid'
      subject.valid?
      expect(subject.errors[:email]).to include(invalid_message)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Care to show how this would be called in the User model?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, but I believe it should just be ```validates :email, email: true```

Answer (score 5):

Try [validates_email_format_of](https://github.com/validates-email-format-of/validates_email_format_of) gem.

Comment: That's a nice, simple gem. Thanks for pointing that one out. I'd much rather use this than inline regex.

Comment: How could I use this library as simple function returning boolean value? Docs shows only usage with error message, but I'd like to avoid throwing error.

Comment: It's not maintained, and there's several false positive issues not being addressed at all. Use wisely.

Comment: I glanced quickly at this gem. Other than maintenance concerns, it's doing a DNS resolutions step. Personally, I do not like the idea of having a network dependency from a validator on a model.

Answer (score 5):

Is better to follow Rails documentation:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
end
```

Comment: Very restrictive (and not even close to the "real" email regex, which is a horrible abuse of regexes :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Your comment is not adding anything to it. Share with us the correct regex/way, please. :)

Comment: Here's what it adds: (1) It's a restrictive regex, e.g., it does not cover many real-world email cases, and (2) hints there's an actual reasonably-complete regex, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/20771794/438992. As the regex is a page long I cannot include it in a comment. For all but the simplest cases (which, fortunately, include a lot of email addresses) a regex is not the best approach.

Comment: the guide was updated https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#strict-validations it uses `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP` now

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: Don't use a regexp. There are too many edge cases and false negatives and false positives. Check for an @ sign and send a mail to the address to validate it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxX81WmXjPg

Comment: while this works for sign up it would be too complex for simple data collection, e.g. website contact forms

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
validates_format_of  :email, :with => /^[\+A-Z0-9\._%-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

Answer (score 3):

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
!("yourmail@example.com" =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX).nil?
```

Comment: Very restrictive (and not even close to the "real" email regex, which is a horrible abuse of regexes :)

Answer (score 3):

Please, be aware that for now **email_validator** gem does not have complex validation rules, but only:

```
/[^\s]@[^\s]/
```

https://github.com/balexand/email_validator/blob/master/lib/email_validator.rb#L13

Argumentation is in https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it was fixed with a simple one-line gem

```
gem 'validates_email_format_of'
```

in my model I added

```
validates :email, email_format: { message: 'Invalid email format' }
```

I hope this helps any newbie's like myself :)