# SAS regex issue

Tags: regex, sas

I have a question related to regex in SAS, where ia mtesting Email field.
below is my code:

```
    data temp;
    set cont_data1;
    if prxmatch("/[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-
    zA-Z]{2,4}/",EMAIL) > 0 then found=1;
    else found=0;
    RUN;
```

but it gives me syntax error:I dont know what should be change.
Can anyone give me correct syntax for this regex?

Comment: Share some input and output examples

Comment: Validating emails with a regex is a serious task. Look at [this mega regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex) which is for perl-based regex engines.

Comment: Use POSIX [:punct:] instead of putting all the characters one by one in your character class. However there are few which you need to put separately such as "?","$","+" etc. Something like this:- prxmatch("m/[[:alnum:][:punct:]?+$|}{]/",EMAIL) > 0

Comment: @ G.Arima  I have input as 1) abc@gmail.com which should pass and 2) xyz@yahoo which should fail like that

Comment: @ India.Rocket  can you share the exact regex with the proper syntax for the expression that i shared?

Comment: Try `prxmatch("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\%#~\`=?&\/$^*!{}+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", EMAIL)` - just like [here](https://regex101.com/r/pX475I/1). Do not add any spaces or linebreaks inside.

Answer (score 2):

You may fix your pattern as

```
if prxmatch("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\%#~`=?&\/$^*!{}+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/",EMAIL) > 0 then found=1;
```

Pay attention to

- `\/`  - inside the pattern, the regex delimiter symbol must be escaped
- `\\\\` - turns into `\\`, as you need not escape the backslash for sas here
- `^` / `$` - you need the anchors to match the whole string with the pattern, to prevent partial matches.

Once you udnerstand these changes, you will probably want to have a look at the [mega-email-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex) [mentioned by HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975162/sas-regex-issue#comment74981371_43975162).