# Use of Preg_match to Determine Mobile Number or Email

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm asking if there are better ways of determining what string has been inputted, either a phone number or an email, here are my already working code

```
    public function InviteFriend($invitation)
    {
        // Initialize Connection
        $conn = $this->conn;
        // Check what type of Invitation it is
        if (preg_match_all('~\b\d[- /\d]*\d\b~', $invitation, $res) > 0) {
            $type = 'phone';
        } else if (preg_match_all('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i', $invitation, $res) > 0) {
            $type = 'email';
        }
        echo $type;
    }
```

But my concern is if a user typed both phone and email in the same string, which of the if statement would be picked and which would be ignored? and is my way of determining which type of string proper or is there a more efficient way?
Thanks

Comment: Should it be either phone number or email only?

Comment: Yes it must @revo

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two anchors almost available in all regex flavors which you have used in your second regex for validating an email address, shown as `^` and `$` and meant as beginning and end of input string respectively.

You should use them for first validation as well. Your phone number validation lacks a good validation since it validates an arbitrary sequence of strings like `1-------  --------5` that doesn't look like a phone number and much more things since it doesn't match against whole string (missing both mentioned anchors). So I used `\d{10}` to indicate a 10-digit phone number that you may want to change it to meet your own requirements, this time more precisely.

You don't really want that kind of email validation either. [Something more simpler is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex):

```
public function InviteFriend($invitation)
{
    if (preg_match('~^\d{10}$~', $invitation)) {
        $type = 'phone';
    } else if (preg_match('~^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$~i', $invitation)) {
        $type = 'email';
    }
    echo $type ?? 'Error';
}
```

Comment: You may reduce email validation regular expression by using filter_var.
 filter_var($invitation, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Comment: Yes, that's a choice and I prefer it. Link in my answer points to the same rfc used by this filter.

Comment: @Smartpal I used that too for verification, but determine what a string is, is the actual case scenario here and doing it the right way

Comment: @PreciousTom You have to force user to input either phone or email, user enter both or invalid data send invalid response.

Comment: Didn't you find out how to *determine what a string is* by this answer? @PreciousTom

Comment: @PreciousTom revo's answer is almost correct add **else** with $type = 'Invalid' then check for type if it's invalid send invalid response to user.

Comment: Minutes before your comment I modified answer. @Smartpal