# How to recursively scrape email addresses from files with Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, extract

I try to scrape emailaddresses with Powershell from a directory, with subdirectories and within them .txt files. So i have this code:

```
$input_path = ‘C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape’
$output_file = ‘C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape\output.txt’
$regex = ‘\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

But when I execute it, it gives me an error

```
select-string : The file C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape\ can not be read: Could not
path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape\'.
At line:1 char:1
+ select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessingFile,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

I've tried variations to the $input_path, with Get-Item, Get-ChildItem, -Recurse, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone figure out how I need to scrape my location and all its subdirectories and files for the regex pattern?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but if you need to get a list of TXT files from a directory structure, you need something like this: `Get-ChildItem -Path $input_path -Include "*.txt" -Recurse`

Comment: I dont think thats the correct regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `Select-String` assumes the `-Path` points to a file or is a wildcard pattern, and `$input_path` is pointing to a folder.  You could use:

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape\*.txt'
Select-String $input_path ....
```

However, since you want to recurse through subdirectories, you'll need to use `Get-ChildItem` to do that.

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape'
$output_file = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape\output.txt'
$regex = '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'

Get-ChildItem $input_path -Include *.txt -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
    Set-Content $output_file
```

---

Note that your regex may cause problems here.  You're using `\b` for word boundary, but period `.`, hyphen `-`, and percent sign `%` are all non-word (`\W`) characters.  The word characters (`\w`) are `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

For example:

```
PS C:\> '%username@example.com' -match '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'
True
PS C:\> $Matches.Values
username@example.com
```

If that's what you want the pattern to do, that's great, but it is something to be aware of. [Regex for an email address](https://emailregex.com/) is [notoriously difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex).

Answer (score 0):

Your correction didn't work but gave me another error, @Bacon Bits. However you put me on the right track. I adapted a bit and this seemed to work out for me.

`$input_path = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape'`
`$output_file = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\toscrape\output.txt'`
`$regex = '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'`

`Get-ChildItem $input_path -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file`