# Regular expression for email address that accepts apostrophe

Tags: regex, angular, email

Want to add "'" i.e. apostrophe to the email address

The code I have works fine except for that it doesn't accept "'".

```
/^[a-z0-9._%+'-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

I want the apostrophe to be accepted as a valid character in the email address.

Comment: There is a `'` in the `[a-z0-9._%+'-]` class. What are the strings that fail?

Comment: Please add the code you are using the regex in.

Comment: Even when ' is added it seems to be not working.

Comment: Please show the code you are using the regex in.

Comment: I am using Angular 6, and this is how I have used the regex:            
emailAddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100), Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]]

Comment: How is the `this.emailPattern` regex declared?

Comment: There is always some risk, if you want to regex an email address. As in your case you must include a valid character into your regex that you didn't think about beforehand. What if you some day need to add another new character, and another ...? I personally would go with the most basic validation: Contains a `@`. Also see this: [SE - Mail::RFC822::Address Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Try use `\` before the `'` `"`,
like:

```
^[\w\'\"]+([.][\w\'\"]+)*@[\w\'\"]+([.][\w\'\"]+)+$
```

Comment: The `'` and `"` chars are not special in a JavaScript regex and need no escaping. Besides, if what you posted is a string literal, this won't work as unknown escape sequences will be stripped of a backslash.