# validating an email with regexp multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a valid `regexp` for my email validation requirement. I tried several times, but it buggy.

here is my try: `.*@[^\W_]+(?:[\w-]*[^\W_])`

need to fit with:

```
xxx@_domain.com => invalid @ starts with _
xxx@domain_.com => invalid domain ends with _ 
xxx@-domain.com => invalid @ starts with - ( hypen)
xxx@domain-.com => invlaid domain ends with - (hypen)
-xxx@domain.in => invalid domain start with - (hypen)
xxx@111.com => invalid domain only contains numbers
xxx@1and1.com => valid domain contains both number and chars
xxx@us.com => valid
xxx@my-india.com => valid
xxx@me2.com => valid
xxx@tv.com =>
xxx@abc_efg.com =>  valid _ inside the chars
_muth@tamil.com => valid _ start with
```

any one help me?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex

Comment: Try it like this `^[^\s\W-]+(?:[_-][^\s\W_])*@(?![\d._-]+\.[^\W_]+$)[^\W_]+(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*\.[^\W_]+$` https://regex101.com/r/LVWh7m/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - yours works. please place as answer to accept

Comment: @3gwebtrain The question is marked as duplicate. Does the duplicate contain a working solution for you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird - nope, that's not such clear.

Comment: And your regex make this valid, see the this xx-u@my-india.commmmm` - need to restrict with 2 or 3 letters after dot operator

Comment: @3gwebtrain I have added a slighty modified version as an answer for your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific requirements you might use

```
^\w+(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*@(?![\d._-]+\.[^\W_]+$)[^\W_]+(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*\.[^\W_]{2,3}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `-` or `-` and 1+ word chars except `_`
- `@` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `[\d._-]+\.[^\W_]+$` Assert only digits or any of `._-` until the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ times a word char except `_`
- `(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `-` or `-` and 1+ word chars except `_`
- `\.[^\W_]{2,3}` Match `.` and 2-3 times a word char except `_`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZE3UDt/1)

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thanks for details

Answer (score 1):

If this email value comes from a HTML input, i think the best way is to just set the `type` property to email and let the browser do the hard work, but if this is not the case, you can check [Regexr](https://regexr.com/), there's some community regex already created and it's quite a useful tool

Comment: He definetly has to check some online regexp tester. His expression fail to match any emails supplied.

Comment: What I mean by “fails to match” is that it matches just about any string.