# Regex for Date and time picker javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to find regex for a date and time picker in JavaScript

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQWgO.png]

which format is hh/mm ampm and dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm ampm.

I tried `([0-3][0-9])([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])-\d{4} ( ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-4]):[0-5][0-9])` but doesnt seem to work cuz / apparently is not a normal simbol.

What is the correct regular expresion? RegEx has always been hard for me

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for editing! However it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

If those are the standard `<input type="datetime" />` and variants thereof, then you should really do some **basic debugging**.

```
console.log(datetimeInput.value);
// 2020-08-17 23:33:05
```

Date and time inputs are displayed in the user's local format, but they are internally stored in [the correct format](https://xkcd.com/1179/). Furthermore, they are validated automatically by the browser, so there should be no need whatsoever to run a regex over them.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was trying to do a regex simply cuz our lecturer asked us to use 6 regex input validation in a html form: (

Comment: Regex validation is obsolete in most common cases. We have `<input type="email" />` so no need for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex). We have `<input type="datetime-local" />` so no need for date validation. We have `<input type="number" />` so no need for `/\d+/`.

Comment: Thanks, just finished all the regex validations

Answer (score -1):

you try this one for date and time:

```
/^([0-9]{2}\/){2}\d{4}\s[0-2][0-9]\:[0-6][0-9]\s(pm|am)$/
```

and this one for time:

```
/^[0-2][0-9]\:[0-6][0-9]\s(pm|am)$/
```

```js
const regex = /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}\d{4}\s[0-2][0-9]\:[0-6][0-9]\s(pm|am)$/;

const regex_time = /^[0-2][0-9]\:[0-6][0-9]\s(pm|am)$/;

console.log(regex.test("09/09/2020 12:60 pm"))
console.log(regex.test("09/09/2020 12:60 am"))
console.log(regex_time.test("12:60 am"))
console.log(regex_time.test("12:60 pm"))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks: ) but it doesnt work for me. Besides I was looking for dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm ampm

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your reply: ) I also rekon it works but it doesnt. it matches with 09/09/2020 12:60 pm perfectly but when I put it in my website it doesnt match. Is it because the value is not 09/09/2020 12:60 pm?

Comment: <input type="datetime-local" name="myTime" id="datetime" />
this is the picker

Comment: check what's the value you getting from the input and try to make a string maybe anyway   try to make something similar to what i am testing with

Comment: and this regex works perfectly for all time not only `09/09/2020 12:60 pm`