# Regex match emails separated only one semicolon

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I have regex allows input emails separated by many semicolons, enters (new line char), spaces and tabs.
I would like to limit the number of semicolons to a maximum of one and not allow input new line char, spaces and tabs. Could anyone to help me rebuild my regex below?

```
isValid = element.match(/^\w+([-+.\']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/)
```

Comment: I mean that's nice and all but email regex is actually really complicated... https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773069/398519  But more to the point, do you want Javascript to handle this or C# to handle it?

Comment: Exactly in TS Angular.

Comment: I don't know if there a more confortable way, but you can use `^\w+([-+.\']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*(;\w+([-+.\']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*){0,1}`. See that is  `--your original reg-expr--(;--your original reg-expr--){0,1}`

Comment: @Eliseo Not is not working correctly.