# SQL Split String?

Tags: sql, split

I have read over a lot of the examples on here regarding split string however, none are really helping me.

My SQL 'skills' are pretty basic however i have this:

```
SELECT [ID]
,[Text]
,[Date]
FROM [dbo].[notes]
Where [Text] like '%@%'
```

Which will return data like:

```
| ID | Text                                      | Date                    |
|----|-------------------------------------------|-------------------------|
| 1  | the email address is someone@here.com     | 2016-05-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | reach me on anotheraddress@this.com ok?   | 2020-12-20 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | new email thisone@here.com                | 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 |
| 3  | oneeamil@here.com anotheremail@there.com  | 2021-01-20 00:00:00.000 |
```

I am hoping to filter/ group by date to get the most recent entry and split out duplicates onto a list like

```
| ID | Email                  |
|----|------------------------|
| 1  | someone@here.com       |
| 2  | thisone@here.com       |
| 3  | oneeamil@here.com      |
| 3  | anotheremail@there.com |
```

I appreciate any help

Thanks :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your result set seems to have no relationship to the same data -- the ids are different.Your question is confusing.

Comment: Do you really need to [extract valid email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773069/2778710) (or [this IETF article](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-seantek-mail-regexen-03.html#rfc.section.3.1.4)) from this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later and you just want space delimited strings that look like emails, then you can use [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select n.*, s.value
from dbo.notes n cross apply
     string_split(n.text, ' ') s
where s.value like '%@%';
```

If you want this limited to only the most recent row per id:

```
select n.*, s.value
from (select n.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from dbo.notes n
     ) n cross apply
     string_split(n.text, ' ') s
where n.seqnum = 1 and s.value like '%@%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2c98ffaad9460b43a2814fb438f0048) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I was looking for, I will test it out soon :)