# regex find text block when it start with but does not contain

Tags: regex

While processing the logs we receive from our routers I'v encountered a problem.
In fact these logs are just scripted console outputs we receive from our network provider.
We have heen able to process some blocks but now I'm encoutering another problem with regex.
This is a sample of the log

```
   PADB067# show vrrp
    % No entries found.
    PADB067# show run vpn 0  | i weight
    PADB067# show run vpn 0 
    vpn 0
     name Transport
     dns 4.2.2.2 secondary
     dns 8.8.8.8 primary
     host vbond-list ip x.x.x.x y.y.y.y z.z.z.z
     interface ge0/0
      description           "ORCH=NETWORK - To INTERNET"
.....
      tunnel-interface
       encapsulation ipsec preference 0
      !
      icmp-redirect-disable
      no shutdown
      shaping-rate          20480
      qos-map               COS-OUT-SHAPED
      bandwidth-upstream    20480
      bandwidth-downstream  20480
     !
     interface ge0/3
      description "ORCH=NETWORK - CUSTOMER LAN - Service VPN physical interface"
      mtu         1504
      no shutdown
    !
    PADB067# show run vpn 1
    vpn 1
```

Some routers don't have all blocks, in this case I want to find the block between "show run vpn 0" and the next routername, this is the regex.

```
(?<=show run vpn 0)(?s)(.*?)(?=PADB067)
```

But I don't want it to start at "show run vpn 0  | i weight", that is another data block (that in this case is not present for that router).
So bottom line I'm searching for the correct regex that would 'think'

Find the text block after "show run vpn 0" when the line does not include "weight", until "PADB067"

Kr, Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the online `(?s)` and then match 1 or more lines that do not start with PAD and a digit if you want a more general approach instead of hardcoded `PADB067`.

Note that there is a space after `vpn 0`  in the example data

```
(?<=show run vpn 0 )(?:\n(?![^\S\n]*PADB\d+\b).*)+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=show run vpn 0 )` Positive lookbehind, assert that the text is directly to the left of the current position
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline (Or use `\r?\n`)
  - `(?![^\S\n]*PADB\d+\b)` Negative lookahead, assert that the string does not start with optional spaces followed by `PADB` and 1 or more digits
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TRYyur/1)

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/PADB067# show run vpn 0/{p=1;next} /PADB067# show run vpn /{exit}p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=show run vpn 0 [\r\n])[\s\S]*?(?=\s*PADB067\b)
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(?<=show run vpn 0 [\r\n])` -- positive lookbehind for expected text and newline
- `[\s\S]*?` -- non-greedy scan (`[\s\S]*?` is any chars including newlines; use `.*?` instead with `s` flag)
- `(?=\s*PADB067\b)` -- positive lookbehind for whitespace and `PADB067` with word boundary

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: What is the difference between `\s\S` and `.` ?

Comment: See regex link. `.` does not match newlines unless you specify the `s` flag. `[\s\S]` means space and non-space, e.g. anything including newlines

Comment: Your link is not compliant with RFC#822 ^^ . I mean the example regex for email.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex

Comment: @GillesQuénot: That is the point, it's futile to do a proper validation based on RFC-822 or RFC-1035, hence do an approximation.

Comment: The `.tld` part is not mandatory. Back in the dayz, there was `dk` domain name **and** `tld`, with `A` and `AAA` records. Don't remember for `MX`, but absolutely faisable. The regex on web sites are often too strict and broken. `\b[\w.%+-]+@\w` should be sufficient

Comment: @GillesQuénot: Agree if you do email verification round trip. This is mainly an educational exercise in the slides.