Regular Expression for Multiple Email addresses separated with a single space and not ending with space
I want to come up with a Regular Expression for multiple email addresses separated by a single space and not ending with space and it should accept one or more emails.
The email validation and the double space are working fine with me but I am stuck with the "not ending with space" part.
I am using below which is working for everything mentioned expect that it MUST have an ending space:
^((?:([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\b {1}))+$


just get the string and do a trim? regex by itself is already complex, a true email validation regex is out of this word (yours is missing a lot by the way), why complicate things when you can make it simpler? Here is just one of many on how complex it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771794/mailrfc822address-regex

two possible approaches

1..n emails followed by optional space
0..n emails followed by one space plus 1 email followed by no space

the first approach would also match for two emails separated with no space. But as you also have the \b before the space in your regex the validation will be ok with this simpler first approach. Instead of \b {0,1} you could also write \b ?
^((?:([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\b {0,1}))+$

or
^((?:([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\b {1}))*((?:([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\b))+$



short answer (combined with ideas from other answers)
^(?:[\w.%+-]+@[\w.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b ?)+$


Only the second one (the long one) looks working with me for all scenarios. Thanks.

The long one is an invalid regex: it has more opening parentheses than closing ones.

@trincot added one missing closing parenthesis

Some remarks on your attempt:

\b is not necessary where you have it. It is already implied by the preceding match of a letter, and the required space that must follow.

{1} is useless, as without it you already have the same requirement.

In most regex implementations, [A-Za-z0-9_] can be written as \w, and when you have more allowable characters, you can combine, like [\w.%+-]

You have a (?:  ) group that isn't serving any purpose as it is immediately wrapped in a (  ) group.


As to the solution to forbid the terminating space, you can use (?:^|\b ) at the start of the repeating group, meaning that either the email address should start at the beginning of the input, or it should be preceded by a space that follows a word break.
Taking all that together:
^(?:(?:^|\b )([\w.%+-]+@[\w.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}))+$


Well explained trincot ! it's working with me much appreciated..

I just noticed your Regex is not enforcing to have a space between emails. So concatenated emails are accepted and emails separated by comma or any delimiter other than space is accepted as well.

I cannot reproduce that. On regex101 you cannot leave out the space between emails nor separate them by commas. See tests on regex101. Please clarify how you have produced those results?

Please clarify how you have produced those results?

My results showed when using this this regex tester I found online: https://regexr.com/

Did you set the m flag so you can test with multiple inputs, each on a separate line? If you didn't, and entered many inputs, then it will not work. Then you can only test with one input at a time. See it work on that site with this saved regex

If you try the same site in the test mode, not in the text search mode, you'll see the cases I mentioned are failing.

Anyhow many thanks for the support, it looks the scenarios are bit tricky and different results are showing with different Regex Testers.

I don't understand. It works fine in tester mode. See here. Can you provide a saved link to what you say is failing?
