# How does the python regex [^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+ work in checking emails?

Tags: python, regex, email

(from [Python check for valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address))

I don't completely understand

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

Can someone explain this in detail?

Comment: Type in your regex at http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl and see for yourself.  Voting to close.

Comment: This answer from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) may also be of interest: [validating email addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) as listed under "Common Validation Tasks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks for 1+ non-`@` characters, followed by an `@`, followed by 1+ non-`@` characters, followed by a `.`, followed by 1+ non-`@` characters.

[`[]`s denote a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and the `^` negates the character class. [`+` matches 1+](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of the preceding characters. Finally, the `.` is escaped like `\.` because the [`.` is a reserved symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) meaning "any character".

This means it isn't the *best* method for checking emails, since there are a lot more restrictions.  For example, this would validate a 10,000 character long email or an email with a domain like `!@#.com`.

Get used to using a tool like [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dL8gE7) for testing expressions and getting good descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

`[^@]+` - checks for anything that is not the `@` symbol, one or more times.

`@` searches for the `@` symbol, clearly.

`\.` searches for the `.` character (it must be escaped since `.` searches for any character)

So it looks for any string not containing `@`, followed by `@`, followed by any string not containing `@`, followed by `.`, followed by any string not containing `@`.

Answer (score 0):

A proper validator for the [RFC822 address specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) (section "6. ADDRESS SPECIFICATION" on page 27) is a bit more complex than a small regex.

In order to do this properly, a grammar would be needed(like the one described in said rfc) but a regex works too. Such a regex can be found in the [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid) module, more exactly [right here](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Email-Valid-1.193/lib/Email/Valid.pm#L400). I haven't tried that regex in Python(but it works fine in Perl).

AFAIK that's the de facto way of checking if an e-mail address is rfc822-valid. Also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/827519) for more details.

But to answer your question now, the regex `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+` reads as "At least one or more non-@ , then a @ , then at least one or more non-@ , then a dot, then at least one or more non-@".

Comment: The de facto way of determining if an e-mail address is valid is *sending an e-mail*. If it bounces or the mailer reports an error, it's invalid.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding, I meant valid as in rfc822-valid (as can be read above^^)

Comment: Yes, that's a more accurate way to word it.