# How can I write a simple email validation program in Python?

Tags: python, validation, email, split, alphanumeric

This may seem a stupid question, but how can I write a simple email validation program in Python? I'm quite new to the software and I've missed a couple of IT lessons, so I really have no idea what to do.

This is as far as I've gotten (yes, I know it doesn't do anything useful):

```
email = input ("Please type in an email address ")
splitemail = email.split('@')
emailstr = ''.join(splitemail)
splitemail2 = emailstr.split('.')
print (splitemail2)
```

The email needs to have this pattern: [alphanumeric character(s)] @ [alphanumeric character(s)] . [alphanumeric character(s)]

Then the program must determine whether is is valid or not and output 'VALID' or 'INVALID'.

Thanks for reading, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about regexes? Should be helpful in this case

Comment: No, I think I saw those mentioned when I was trying to research this problem but I haven't used them before.

Comment: Try writing some pseudocode first

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Sorry - I didn't really know anything about regex before I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some regular expressions to validate and split the given email adress.
The code would then look like this

```
import re
email = input ("Please type in an email address ")
if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)@(?P<domain>[\w\-_]+).(?P<toplevel>[\w]+)\Z",email,re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Email is valid")
else:
    print("Email is invalid")
```

For information aboout regualr expressions take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Here a [link](http://www.pythonregex.com/) for easily testing your expression.

Comment: Thank you - it's a bit different from what I've covered so far but it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Underscores are not allowed in domain name labels. This also rejects many valid addresses.

Comment: You are right, the regualr expression i gave is not validating all possible emailadresses. If some one really want to know how to get a regular expression for most/all email adresses take a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string.isalum()` function to solve this.

example:

```
def validate(mystring):
    if mystring.isalnum():
        print "VALID"
    else:
        print "INVALID"
```

Here is an example in-out:

```
IN   mystring = "alphanum1234"
OUT  VALID

IN   mystring = "alpha num 1234"
OUT  INVALID

IN   mystring = "alpha.num-1234"
OUT  INVALID
```

Comment: There is a typo in the first line of this post, it should read string.isalnum() not .isalum()

Answer (score -1):

Read about regex they should help you :) a useful regex for validating emails is :

```
[A-Za-z0-9-_]+(.[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(.[A-Za-z]{2,})
```

An explanation of this can be found [here](http://regex101.com/r/jS2jR5/1)

Here are some good tutorials to start with for regex :

http://fr.slideshare.net/absherzad/java-regular-expression-part-i

http://fr.slideshare.net/absherzad/java-regular-expression-part-ii

And here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address) on SE concerning validating emails in python using regex

Comment: Thank you for your answer - these are really helpful to me.

Comment: But don't use this in real life, as it rejects many valid addresses.

Comment: @tripleee an exemple of an email that will not match ?

Comment: `ick..bar@example.com`; `moo+boo!far%quux*bar~zoo@example.net`