# Pseudocode for email address verification (language using is Python)

Tags: pseudocode

I would like some help on how to do a pseudocode for checking the formatting of an email is correct. I am using Python but need to plan it out first

Generic Rules:
1. alphnumeric before @
2. @ 
3. Alphnumeric after @
4. . (dot) after @

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a given email address exists or not in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625672/how-to-check-whether-a-given-email-address-exists-or-not-in-python)

Comment: You are missing characters such as `-_.+` etc. E-mail validation that really works 99.99% is very painful. You should take a look at http://emailregex.com/ and http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python check for valid email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: And 99.99% is not so great if you have 10M users.