# Python simple email validity check

Tags: python

In Python, if i wanted to write something that returns a boolean True as long as the @ symbol appears after the . symbol, how would I write this?

I have tried writing something like:

```
if myString[x] == "@" > myString[x] == ".":
     return True
```

but, I assume that this won't work because they're both essentially the same index. Looking for some explanation as well, just learning a lot of basics still. 
Thanks!

Comment: you want to know if the @ appears after or before `.` for email validation?

Comment: `this.is.a.valid@email.address` and you algorithm fails this.

Comment: For email address checking, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address.

Comment: I appreciate the info, I'm actually just trying to write this poor function for an assignment and having trouble. I understand that this wouldn't work well if I tried to implement this in the real world. Thanks for the info, though!

Comment: If it is homework, you should do it yourself. If you don't know the basics, like how to find the position of `@` and `.` in a string, google *"find position of character in string python"*

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if str.index('@') > str.index('.'):
   return True;
```

Comment: This will result in an error if the string does not contain `@` or `.`

Comment: Addtionally, it would be better to simply do `return str.index('@') > str.index('.')`

Comment: @Efferalgan : He was just asking about the syntax if you have read the question correctly. Moreover, the email validity itself is wrong as @>. is not a correct way to verify email.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regular expression:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')

string = """This text contains an email@address.com somewhere"""

if rx.search(string):
    print("Somewhere in there is an email address")
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/7FpfgH).

Comment: This does not satisfy the constraints of the question (although it may of course satisfy the constraints of reality)

Comment: @NickBastin: Good Points - both :)

Answer (score 1):

`return str.find('@') > str.find('.') and str.find('.') > -1`

This will check that `@` is after `.`, and that both symbols are present in the string. This is however a **very** bad way to check for email validity.