# while loop in a python class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to incorporate a regex check for user input in my class. I want a scenario where users can't proceed to enter their name until they enter a valid email address. The current code i have isn't working as expected.

I suppose a while-loop is in order here but i am struggling to implement that in this class. Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
class test:  
 def __init__(self):     
    self.email = input("Enter your email: ")
    email_check = re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+.\w+', self.email)
    if email_check:
        print ('email valid')
    else:
        print ('email not valid')
        self.email = input("Enter your email: ")            
        sys.exit(0)
     self.name = input("Enter your name:  ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
while True:
    self.email = input ("Enter email:")
    if valid_email:
        break
```

Substitute `valid_email` with your way of validating the email address.

You may also be interested in [Python check for valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address) for ways to validate an email address.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what  i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should not implement any activity of this kind into `__init__` method, as one is intended for object fields initialization first place. Consider dedicated 'check_email' method, or whatever name applies best.

Now, regarding your case:

```
class test:
    def __init(self):
       # whatever initialization applies
       pass

    def init_emails():
        emails = []
        proceed = True
        # if you really in need of do/while loop
        while proceed:
            email = self.input_email()
            # your logic for input
            if email is not None:
                emails.append(email)
            # invalid input or cancel
            else:
                 proceed = False
        return input

     def input_email(self):
         value = input('Enter your email:')
         # TODO: validate/check input
         return proper_value
```

Comment: I second the comments that this doesn't belong in `__init__` or probably even in a class at all. User interaction should probably happen outside the class unless it is specifically a class to implement user interaction. Your class should probably just `raise` an error if it finds itself populated with invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class test:  
     def __init__(self):     
         self.email = self.get_name()

     def get_name(self) :
         while True:
            x = input("Enter your email: ")
            if (re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+.\w+', x)) :
                return x
```

Answer (score 0):

This script functions as described, in the end printing the name and email. If you need to use python2.7, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. I used `for i in range` instead of `while True` to avoid an endless loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.email = None
        self.name = None

    def get_email(self):
        for i in range(3):
            email = input('Enter your email: ')
            if re.search('[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+.\w+', email):
                return email
        print('Too many failed attempts!')
        sys.exit(1)

    def get_name(self):
        for i in range(3):
            name = input('Enter your name: ')
            if name:
                return name
            print('Too many failed attempts!')
            sys.exit(1)

    def initialize(self):
        self.email = self.get_email()
        self.name = self.get_name()
        print('"{}" <{}>'.format(self.name, self.email))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    t.initialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of input, try to use raw_input. Like this:

```
self.email = raw_input("Enter your email:")
```

There'll be no error anymore.
Hope this helps.

Comment: In Python 3, 'input` is the equivalent of Python 2's `raw_input` (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/). Based on the usage of the print function (rather than statement) in the original code, I would assume the OP is using Python 3.