# Regex email validation Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, regex, python-2.7

I'm having trouble fully understanding this Python 2 regular expression to validate email addresses. I found a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address).

```
r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+"
```

So according to [regex101](https://regex101.com) this means we need atleast 1 value before the '@' symbol, 1 '@' symbol, and any number of characters after the '@' symbol and atleast 1 '.' symbol. First of all correct me if I'm wrong, but secondly no documentation anywhere explains what "[^@]" means. So I'm having trouble understanding what the above code means.

All I would like to do is convert the above code to Javascript but have only found help with the following case:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

This means very little to me, but have found this useful example [here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php). The problem is that the JavaScript expression over checks.

For example, the following string passes in Python but fails the JS expression:

```
hi@gmail.com.edu/org
```

It really comes down to 1 question. **How can I correct the JavaScript regex to match that of the Python regex?**

Comment: `[^@]` => [Negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Not `@`

Comment: No need to change anything in regex, [use it as it is](https://regex101.com/r/PEfZAx/1). And, maybe add anchors.

Comment: Hi @Tushar the python regex is correct, it is the javascript I'm worried about.

Comment: The python regex can be used as is in JavaScript: `/[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/`

Comment: wow. stupid me, I was unaware that the regex transferred so well. @4castle please submit your solution so I can mark as correct.

Comment: @Tushar ahh yes. I didn't originally realize that that was submitted in JS. Please submit your solution below. What anchors would be necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply convert python regex to Javascript.

Python: `r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+"`

Javascript: `/[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/`