# Separating characters of a string into a list (python)

Tags: python, list, validation

I am writing a program which is like an email validator, the user enters their email and then the program checks it has the necessary components. I have to check it contains an @ sign. I want to split the email character by character and put it into a list so that I can loop through the list to get the email.

I currently have this:

```
email=input('Please enter your email address: ')
mylist=[]
mylist(email)
for i in mylist:
    if i != '@':
        at=True
        print('Your email is invalid because it does not contains an @ sign.')
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert a string to a list? You can just use `for i in email` directly. Or better still, just test for that one character: `if '@' not in email:`

Comment: Otherwise, just use `mylist = list(email)`.

Comment: use regex to validate an email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to convert a string into a list in order to iterate over it.
In Python, a string is already iterable, so you can do:

```
for c in email:
    if c != '@':
        print(...)
```

But Python offers you a better construct, the `in` operator:

```
if '@' not in email:
    print(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
if '@' not in email:
    print('Your email is invalid because it does not contains an @ sign.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if a string has a character inside, you can use:

```
if char in string:
```

So in your case:

```
if '@' in email:
    print("This appears to be a valid email.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use python-regex?
It is relatively fast.

put this in if clause :-

`for i in mylist:

    email_addr = re.search(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", i) 
    if email_addr:
       print email_addr.group()
    else:
       print 'incorrect format'`

and retreive the address using email_addr.group()
and you are good to go.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use regex to archive what you want

```
list = ['email@emailprovider.com', 'not_an_email']
for email in list:
    if not re.match('(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)', email):
        print('Your email ({}) is invalid because it does not contains an @ sign.'.format(email))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python strings are already iterable. So, you can use the following code to achieve what you want.

```
email = input("Enter your email")     
if '@' not in email:
    print("The email is invalid as it does not contains @.")
else:
    print("valid email")
```