# How to add an email into a path in Django 2.0.1?

Tags: python, django

I want to add an email into a path in Django. I did this code but I don't know how take the variable called email after username place.

```
path('validate_email/<slug:username>/(?P<email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/<slug:token>', views.validate_email, name="validate_email")
```

Comment: If can send me any documentation to read more about the regex please I will be very congratulate with your.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982264/8150371  , https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485817/8150371

Comment: Sorry i dont explain very well. The validate email is when i send a email to confirm the account when you are sing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a regex with `path()`. If you want to use a regex you'll need to use `re_path()` or `url()`.

It might be easier to use simply `<email>` in the URL pattern, then you can validate the email in the view.

```
 path('validate_email/<slug:username>/<email>/<slug:token>', views.validate_email, name="validate_email")
```

Comment: simply replace url with re_path if you don't want to do additional validation in view:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path