# Countif pandas python for multiple columns with wildcard

Tags: python, pandas, countif

I have a dataset in Excel that I would like to replicate.

[image]

My python code looks like:

```
data_frames = [df_mainstore, df_store_A, df_store_B]
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=["Id_number"], how='outer'), data_frames)
print(df_merged)
```

Since I merge several dataframes (can vary in column number and name) it would be tedious too write out all the columns which is done in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810526/countif-in-pandas-python-over-multiple-columns-with-multiple-conditions):

```
isY = lambda x:int(x=='Y')
countEmail= lambda row: isY(row['Store Contact A']) + isY(row['Store B Contact'])
df['Contact Email'] = df.apply(countEmail,axis=1)
```

I also struggle with the expression: `isY = lambda x:int(x=='@')`

How can I add the "Contact has Email" column in a similar way I would do in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `filter` to select columns with Contact in it, then use `str.contains` with the right [pattern for email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148909/9274732) and finally you want `any` per row so:

```
#data sample
df_merged = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2,3], 
                          'Store A': list('abcd'),
                          'Store Contact A':['aa@bb.cc', '', 'e', 'f'], 
                          'Store B': list('ghij'),
                          'Store B Contact':['kk@ll.m', '', 'nn@ooo.pp', '']})

# define the pattern as in the link
pat = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"
# create the column as wanted
df_merged['Contact has Email'] = df_merged.filter(like='Contact')\
                                          .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(pat))\
                                          .any(1)

print (df_merged)
   id Store A Store Contact A Store B Store B Contact  Contact has Email
0   0       a        aa@bb.cc       g         kk@ll.m               True
1   1       b                       h                              False
2   2       c               e       i       nn@ooo.pp               True
3   3       d               f       j                              False
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!! Really appreciated. To make it work 100% I needed to adjust that all the word "Contact" start with a capital `C`.
Furthermore I used the regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+` to make it somewhat more dynamic. Really happy for all the help and input :)!

Comment: @Wizhi if you not always have capital `C`, you can also use `filter(regex='Contact|contact')` for example, but there are more flexible way I'm sure. Glad it helps anyway :)

Comment: Might I ask, If I would like to return all the emails instead of True/False value, how should I proceed then? or is it more appropriate to ask a new question :)?

Comment: @Wizhi you can try `df_merged['Store Contact A'].str.extract(pat)` where pat is slightly different `pat = r"([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)"` note the `()` around the regex you did but if you want a working solution, maybe a new question would be better

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I will try to play around with your suggestion. If I don't solve it I will ask a new question. Thanks again!! :)!

Comment: @Wizhi not sure how you want the result, but this `df_merged.filter(like='Contact').apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(pat)[0]).agg(list, axis=1)` gives a list of all the email per row

Comment: That works really good, exactly what I needed!!, much better than my workaround solution!!! Thanks again :)!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df_merged['Contact has Email'] = df_merged['Store Contact A'].str.contains('@', na=False)|df_merged['Store B Contact'].str.contains('@', na=False)
```