# Is there a way to check whether a person inputs a valid email without regex - python

Tags: python

In my signup form of my website, I'd like to check whether the person inputs an 'email' and not anything else. This is my signup function in python:

```
@app.route('/Signup', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['password'] == request.form['repeatpass']:
            _insertuser(request.form['name'], request.form['email'], request.form['password'], request.form['repeatpass'])
            return render_template('SignedUp.html')
        else:
            session['credentials wrong'] = True
            return render_template('Signup.html')
    else:
        session['credentials wrong'] = False
        return render_template('Signup.html')
```

In most cases people use regex, however I find regex slightly complicated and would like to know if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I would suggest just about anything but writing your own regex to validate email addresses.

Comment: This should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address

Comment: short answer. no