# How to turn an any() statment negative in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean, any

I'm creating a check for input e-mails to see if they only use specific charakters. I wanted to use an any() statment that basically means 
"if any item from the e-mail isn't in goodCharsEmail, do ..." 
I came up with this:

```py
newEmail = ["m", "a", "i", "l", "@", "d", "o", "m", "a", "i", "n", ".", "c", "o", "m"] 

goodCharsEmail = ["a", "b", "c", "etc..."]

check =  any(item in newEmail for item in goodCharsEmail)
if check == True:
    print("bad request")
    quit
```

But I obviously need to make the any() statment negative, because at the moment it does the exact opposite of the wanted result. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you're looking for `not all()`

Comment: Or `any(item not in...)`

Comment: As an aside, it would be better to make `newEmail` a set.

Comment: I'm confused about `goodCharsEmail`. Are you saying that any character in `newEmail` must be a character in one of the elements in `goodCharsEmail`? Is `goodCharsEmail` a list of allowable characters, or a list of allowable email addresses?

Comment: a list of acceptible charakters

Comment: @Boris Thank you, I'm pretty new to python. I don't really understand how alkasm's "not all()" should work and Daniel Roseman's "any(item not in...)" doesn't work for me either ---> "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable".

Comment: @1337HaxX0r I think those people missed that you're iterating over each character in `good_chars_email` and checking if they're in the email, when you should be iterating over the characters in the email and checking if they're in `good_chars_email` instead. Like this: `check = not all(c in good_chars_email for c in new_email)` or `check = any(c not in good_chars_email for c in new_email)`

Comment: Also, strings already behave like lists of characters, so you can just do `new_email = "mail@domain.com"` and `good_chars_email = "abc... etc"` and all your code will work exactly the same.

Comment: Finally, if you're trying to check that an email address is a valid email address, you should just use the `email.utils.parseaddr` function. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485817/3064538

Comment: @Boris it works perfectly! Thank you so much! For me you've been the only user on here actually being helpful and cooperative to new contributors like me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you're new to python, I will try to be very thorough. Please excuse me if some of this is repetition.

First, let's look at what `any()` does. The simplest way is probably to write our own simple implementation:

```
def any(sequence):
    for value in sequence:
        if value:
            return True
    return False
```

In English: it returns `True` if-and-only-if *any* value in the sequence is "true-ish" (e.g. a non-zero integer, a non-empty list, a non-empty string, and so on).

Since `all()` was mentioned in the comments, let's do the same for that one:

```
def all(sequence):
    for value in sequence:
        if not value:
            return False
    return True
```

In English: it returns `True` if-and-only-if *all* values in the sequence are true-ish. Very similar to `any()`, isn't it?

Second, let me note a thing about python strings: they can often be thought of as lists of characters, and handled as such. In other words, there is no need to separate the characters into a list of separate one-character strings.

Third, I believe your problem is not with the `any()` function, but with your list comprehension (the expression inside the parentheses). You see, `item in newEmail for item in goodCharsEmail` means that you're checking whether every character in `goodCharsEmail` is present in `newEmail`. What you really want is the other way around: is every character in `newEmail` one of the good characters?

You could write this with `all`:

```
not all(c in goodCharsEmail for c in newEmail)
```

...or `any`:

```
any(c not in goodCharsEmail for c in newEmail)
```

These two are equivalent -- pick the one you think is easier to read and understand.

The key to understanding these comprehension expressions may be to understand how the parts interact. `c in goodCharsEmail for c in newEmail` means `evaluate the expression "c in goodCharsEmail" for every c in newEmail`.

So, here's how I would rewrite the validation code you posted to make it work:

```
newEmail = "mail@domain.com" 
goodCharsEmail = "@.abcdefghijkl..." # TODO: more chars, probably
if any(c not in goodCharsEmail for c in newEmail):
    print("bad request")
    quit
```

Finally: email address validation is, unfortunately, much harder than most of us would think. As mentioned in [this blog post](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/), all of the following (and more!) are *valid* email addresses:

- "Fred Bloggs"@example.com
- $A12345@example.com
- !def!xyz%abc@example.com

Your approach is fine if you're just practicing in a new programming language. If you're coding the validation for some app or website that other people are going to use, it may cause some frustration.

Have fun! :)

Comment: Thank you both for explaining how it needs to be done when you do it somehow my way. I also found this https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/ , what makes it easier and also checks if the email actually exists.