# How to exclude regex matches containing a constant string

Tags: python, regex, expression

I need help understanding exclusions in regex.

I begin with this in my Jupyter notebook:

```
import re

file = open('names.txt', encoding='utf-8')
data = file.read()
file.close()
```

Then I can't get my exclusions to work. The read file has 12 email strings in it, 3 of which contain '.gov'.

I was told this would return only those that are not .gov:

```
re.findall(r'''
    [-+.\w\d]*\b@[-+\w\d]*.[^gov]
''', data, re.X|re.I)
```

It doesn't. It returns all the emails and excludes any characters in 'gov' following the '@'; e.g.:

```
abc123@abc.c     # 'o' is in 'gov' so it ends the returned string there
456@email.edu
governmentemail@governmentaddress.      #'.gov' omitted
```

I've tried using ?! in various forms I found online to no avail.

For example, I was told the following syntax would exclude the entire match rather than just those characters:

```
#re.findall(r'''
#    ^/(?!**SPECIFIC STRING TO IGNORE**)(**DEFINITION OF STRING TO RETURN**)$
#''', data, re.X|re.I)
```

Yet the following simply returns an empty list:

```
#re.findall(r'''
#    ^/(?!\b[-+.\w\d]*@[-+.\w\d]*.gov)([-+.\w\d]*@[-+.\w\d].[\w]*[^\t\n])$
#''', data, re.X|re.I)
```

I tried to use the advice from this question:

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

```
re.findall(r'''

    [-+.\w\d]*\b@[-+\w\d]*./^((?!.gov).)*$/s  # based on syntax /^((?!**SUBSTRING**).)*$/s
                          #^ this slash is where different code starts
''', data, re.X|re.I)
```

This is supposed to be the inline syntax, and I think by including the slashes I may be making a mistake:

```
re.findall(r'''
    [-+.\w\d]*\b@[-+\w\d]*./(?s)^((?!.gov).)*$/  # based on syntax /(?s)^((?!**SUBTRING**).)*$/
''', data, re.X|re.I)
```

And this returns an empty list:

```
re.findall(r'''
    [-+.\w\d]*\b@[-+\w\d]*.(?s)^((?!.gov).)*$  # based on syntax (?s)^((?!**SUBTRING**).)*$
''', data, re.X|re.I)
```

Please help me understand how to use ?! or ^ or another exclusion syntax to return a specified string not containing another specified string.

Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps you could use `[^\s@]+@(?:(?!\.gov)\S)+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/FKBocM/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your regex for recognizing an email address does not look close to being correct. For example, it would accept `@13a` as being valid. See [How to check for valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/how-to-check-for-valid-email-address) for some simplifications. I will use: `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+` with the recommendation that we also exclude space characters and so, in your particular case:

```
^([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s.]+)
```

I also added a `.` to the last character class `[^@\s.]+` to ensure that this represents the top-level domain. But we do not want the email address to end in `.gov`. Our regex specifies toward the end for matching the top-level domain:

1. `\.` Match a period.
2. `[^@\s.]+` Match one or more non-white space, non-period characters.

In Step 2 above we should first apply a *negative lookahead*, i.e. a condition to ensure that the next characters are not `gov`. But to ensure we are not doing a partial match (if the top-level domain were `government`, that would be OK), `gov` must be followed by either white space or the end of the line to be disqualifying. So we have:

```
^([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.(?!gov(?:\s|$))[^@\s.]+)
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjZs5a/2/)

```
import re

text = """abc123@abc.c     # 'o' is in 'gov' so it ends the returned string there
456@email.edu
governmentemail@governmentaddress.      #'.gov' omitted
test@test.gov
test.test@test.org.gov.test
"""

print(re.findall(r'^([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.(?!gov(?:\s|$))[^@\s.]+)', text, flags=re.M|re.I))
```

Prints:

```
['abc123@abc.c', '456@email.edu', 'test.test@test.org.gov.test']
```

So, in my interpretation of the problem `test.test@test.org.gov.test` is OK becuase `gov` is *not* the top-level domain. `governmentemail@governmentaddress.` is rejected simply because it is not a valid email address.

If you don't want `gov` in any level of the domain, then use this regex:

```
^([^@\s]+@(?!(?:\S*\.)?gov(?:\s|\.|$))[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OW8YHQ/1/)

After seeing the `@` symbol, this ensures that what follows is not an optional period followed by `gov` followed by either another period, white space character or end of line.

```
import re

text = """abc123@abc.c     # 'o' is in 'gov' so it ends the returned string there
456@email.edu
governmentemail@governmentaddress.      #'.gov' omitted
test@test.gov
test.test@test.org.gov.test
"""

print(re.findall(r'^([^@\s]+@(?!(?:\S*\.)?gov(?:\s|\.|$))[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)', text, flags=re.M|re.I))
```

Prints:

```
['abc123@abc.c', '456@email.edu']
```

Comment: Awesome! Very helpful. Thanks. Now, I assume you ended it with + instead of * only because a email domain with a single character would be absurd?

Comment: @PeterCharland If you are referring to the final `\.[^@\s]+)`, that does allow a single-character top-level domain, absurd or not. An `*` would allow an an empty top-level domain. You need `\.[^@\s]{2,})` for a minimum of two characters for the top-level domain.

Comment: ah yes I see. Great! Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes about the patterns you tried

- This part of the pattern `[-+.\w\d]*\b@` can be shortened to `[-+.\w]*\b@` as `\w` also matches `\d` and note that it will also not match a dot
- Using `[-+.\w\d]*\b@` will prevent a dash from matching before the `@` but it could match `---a@.a`
- The character class `[-+.\w\d]*` is repeated 0+ times but it can never match 0+ times as the word boundary `\b` will not work between a whitespace or start of line and an `@`
- Note that not escaping the dot `.` will match any character except a newline
- This part `^((?!.gov).)*$` is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) that will, from the start of the string, match any char except a newline asserting what is on the right is not any char except a newline followed by `gov` until the end of the string

One option could be to use the tempered greedy token to assert that after the `@` there is not `.gov` present.

```
[-+.\w]+\b@(?:(?!\.gov)\S)+(?!\S)
```

Explanation about the separate parts

- `[-+.\w]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `\b@` Word boundary and match `@`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `\.gov` Match `.gov`
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `\S` Match a non whitespace char
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is non a non whitespace char to prevent partial matches

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ASYXS7/1)

---

You could make the pattern a bit broader by matching not an `@` or whitespace char, then match `@` and then match non whitespace chars where the string `.gov` is not present:

```
[^\s@]+@(?:(?!\.gov)\S)+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Do8nu8/1)

Comment: Cool! This was helpful, thanks for breaking it down.

Comment: OK, can I check multiple answers?

Comment: @PeterCharland You can upvote answers pressing the up arrow on the left if you have 15 experience points, which you have now :)