# looking for a function for a logon page

Tags: python

I am a beginner to programing. I am trying to use python to create a "logon page". is there a function I can use to make sure that the email must include an @ sign and a period or else it is invalid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: That's not a good condition. What about local email addresses?

Comment: Please try to do your own research before asking and then share the code that you're working with and ask for help on specific parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this validation.

Take a look a this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022584/9921063

Comment: Did you mean to vote to close the question as a duplicate but didn't have rep to do it?