# How to fix issues (like spaces) in-between the email address

Tags: python, regex, nlp

So I recently am trying to extract text from documents using OCR. Sometimes, the OCR adds a "space" in between characters. This becomes an issue when it is an email address.

For e.g.,
**Email:adil.idris2019@gmail.com**   ------> **adil.idris2019@gmail.com**

I am trying to use regex to solve this issue.

```
import re
txt = "wldeub 777-29378-88 @@ Email:adil.idris 2019@gmail.com dfhdu fdlfkos"
txt1 = "Email:michael wobbly@gmail.com 777-123-0000"
txt2 = "Email: john_jebrasky@ gmail.com TX, USA"
txt3 = "john_jebrasky @gmail.com TX, USA"
txt4 = "I am proficient in python. geekcoder 12@gmail.com TX, USA"

out = re.search("Email\:?.+com",txt)
re.sub("Email\:","",re.sub(" ","",out.group(0)))
```

Unfortunately, this is just a hardcoded fix. NOTE: in some cases, the word **Email:** might not be present as a prefix with the email.
What if there is no **Email** or, what if the text does not follow any standard pattern??

Ideal output: **"adil.idris2019@gmail.com"**

Comment: With regular expressions you cannot distinguish between "character rubbish" and "meaningful content". Thus `dfhdu` and `com` is considered the same. Provide more text snippets to eventually see a pattern.

Comment: I have update the question with more examples

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a difficult problem to solve with only regular expressions.
You can try separating it into two steps.

One where you get a (very) rough estimate of what might be an email.

```
((?:[^\"@:+={}()|\s]+ ?){1,3}\@ ?\w+(?: ?\. ?\w+)+)
```

where `[^@:+={}()|\s]` is a complete shot in the dark, but these are characters that I doubt will suddenly pop up as false positives in OCR.
This will essentially try to match 1 to 3 (`{1,3}`) blocks of text possibly separated by spaces (`...\s]+ ?)...`) that don't include an of the characters in `[^@:+={}()|\s]` and come before an `@`. Then it will try to match a sequence of domain names and their extensions (`.co.uk`, `.com`), possibly separated by spaces  `?`.

Then you can remove all the whitespace from the matched sequences, and check if they're a valid email address with a proper library/regex: [How to check for valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/how-to-check-for-valid-email-address)

Not the most clean solution, but I hope it helps.

#### Edit

I see that you're using a capturing group now, that might explain why it didn't work for you if you have tried it. It should be fixed now.

[RegexR example](https://regexr.com/5ngem)

Comment: in the example i gave,
~~~txt4 = "I am proficient in python. geekcoder 12@gmail.com TX, USA"~~~ 
the ideal email id is: geekcoder 12@gmail.com

But i assume you misunderstood it to be as python.geekcoder12@gmail.com. 
There will be only "one space" between the "word" and "@###.co##